Decomposing a finitely generated module over Z into a direct sum
I have seen the theorem that decomposes the module into $\mathbb{Z}^n\oplus \mathbb{Z}/a_1\mathbb{Z} \oplus ... \mathbb{Z}/a_m\mathbb{Z}$, with $a_i | a_{i+1}$. However, I am having some trouble actually decomposing a module in practice.
For example let $M=\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $N=\langle (3,5,10) \rangle$. I think I understand what $M/N$ "looks like", but how do I find $n,a_i$ in the decomposition?
Intuitivlely I would think there has to be $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ in there as the non-torsion part, since the construction is like chopping $M$ into slices, and each slice corresponds with a multiple of $(3,5,10)$. $M/N$ being one slice, I can "walk infinitely" in two different dimensions.
For the torsion part, a lot of the literature suggests finding the Smith normal form of $(3,5,10)^T$. But since the gcd of 3,5,10 is 1, it seems I just get $(1,0,0)^T$. And that doesn't seem to help in figuring out the torsion part.
As far as I understand, the module cannot be torsion free, since I can multiply any element by 30 and get a multiple of $(3,5,10)$, which is $=(0,0,0)$ in $M/N$.
Another theorem states that the torsion part is the direct sum of $(M/N)[p]=\{x\in M/N | p^nx=0$ for some $n\}$ where $p$ divides the annihilator of $M/N$. The annihilator is $(30)$, so I take $p=2,3,5$. $(M/N)[2]=\{(0,0,0),(0,0,15)\}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, etc. Is this the right track? Even if it is, I don't get divisors $a_i$ where one divides the next, though.

"I can multiply any element by $30$ and get a multiple of $(3,5,10)$". That's wrong. For example, $30\cdot(1,0,0)$ is clearly not such a multiple. Similarly, your $2$-torsion calculation is incorrect as well.

Ah, I see! Thank you.
So is $M/N=\mathbb{Z}^2$?
